# BIOS, системные прерывания. int 11h, int 12h в С++ / C

Tags: c++, c, bios, прерывания

Стоит задача получить информацию о компьютере, используя системное прерывание `int 11h`, которое записывает в регистр AX слово состояния (конфигурации). Доступ к прерываниям можно получить из заголовка `dos.h`, однако функция, обеспечивающая работу с прерыванием `int86()` была найдена только в библиотеках и хедерах компилятора за 1993 год, MS Visual 1.52 (1993 г) 16-битный, что мне не подходит, в виду наличия 64-битной ОС. 
Был написан следующий код:

```
/*#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  short a=0;
  __asm
  {       
    int 11h
    mov a, ax
  }
  printf("%d",a);    
  return 0;
}
```

который выводит на экран слово состояния в числовом виде, равном `-14302`. И вроде все устраивает, но есть несколько но, которые не получилось решить:

1. Компилируется этот код тоже только выше указанным компилятором (работаю VirtualBox с Win7 (32 bit)). Точнее, скомпилировать получилось еще в MS Visual C++ 2010 Express, а вот при запуске программы она вылетает и проблема в строчке `int 11h`
2. Это магическое число `-14302` является результатом также и на планшете (Windows 8.1, 32 bit). И на другом компьютере (WinXP, 32 bit).

Второе "но" наталкивает на мысли, что что-то работает неверно. Разве может быть одинаковым слово состояния на 3 абсолютно разных вычислительных устройствах (планшет, ноутбук, компьютер)?
Прошу советов по решению данной задачи.

Comment: Что-то я очень сомневаюсь, что можно получить какую-то *реальную* информацию из этого прерывания... Уж очень она там древняя. Да и потом, вряд ли кроме как из-под DOS'а, это можно использовать.

Comment: @Harry, я понимаю, что оно все древнее, но это лабораторная работа универа, не мои правила. Вот и бьюсь с этим.

Comment: Ну тогда только могу предложить взять виртуалку-DOS, что-то древнее типа Borland C++ 3.1 и посмотреть...

Comment: сейчас информацию о системе обычно получают через wmi. Если нужно именно через 11 прерывание, тогда лучше это все делать на соответствующей системе. На некоторых современных системах уже и биоса как такового нет (есть uefi).

Comment: Посмотрел конфигурацию для вашего значения :) - нет фопа, есть сопроцессор, у вас не XT и не PS, так что говорить о том, что нет мыши, нельзя... видеорежим 80x25, о количестве флопов говорить нельзя, поддержки DMA нет :), 4 COM-порта, игрового порта нет, последовательного принтера нет, 3 параллельных порта... Может, современные все о себе так говорят? на правду, в каком-то смысле, похоже...

Comment: @Harry, информацию я сам без труда из этого числа вытащил, но меня очень смутило, что это число везде.. Поэтому попробую сейчас с DOS, но мне кажется, что просто время потеряю.

Comment: @Harry, а нельзя ли как-то в Linux все это провернуть? Я изначально использовал компилятор gcc, но не смог вообще никак оформить ассемблерскую вставку, чтобы компилятор ее принял, следовательно и попробовать там не могу. Не знаю, конечно, имеет ли это смысл. Но может подскажите что-нибудь.

Comment: Не подскажу, простите уж :( Тем более с Linux'ом...

Comment: Единственный совет, который тут можно дать - таки закопать уже стюардессу :) В том смысле что использовать исключительно виртуалку с голым досом, или досбокс, или что-то в этом роде. В любой современной  ОС это прерывание просто не имеет смысла, и список оборудования получается совсем по-другому.

Comment: *" на 3 абсолютно разных вычислительных устройствах"* -- кстати, в виртуалбоксе, vmware и т.д. можно легко настраивать железячную конфигурацию машин. Поэтому всё просто: подключили/отключили FDD, например, и проверили что int 11h возвращает в обоих случаях. В виртуалке - голый дос, само собой.

Answer (score 2):

Команда прерывание процессора `int X` это указание процесору вызвать функцию адрес которой хранится в таблице **IDT (Interrupt Descriptor Table) (таблица векторов прерываничя)** и вектором **X**. 
При загрузке, BIOS первоночально записывает адреса своих функций, но после загрузки ядра ОС. ОС записывает свои адреса в таблицу **IDT**. Поэтому в определеных ОС Вы будете получать одинаковый ответ.

Для того чтобы сделать `asm` вставку в gcc. В gcc используется AT&T синтаксис ассемблера

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a;
  __asm__(
      "int $0x11\n\t"
     :"=a"(a)
     );
  printf("%d",a);    
  return 0;
 }
```

Но можно использовать и Intel синтаксис

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a;
  __asm__(
         ".intel_syntax noprefix\n\t"
         "int 11h\n\t"
        :"=a"(a)
        );
  printf("%d",a);    
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: А не подскажите, как удовлетворить Ассемблер, который выдает такое: 
"C:\Users\Rob\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPObhob.s: Assembler messages:
C:\Users\Rob\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPObhob.s:23: Error: operand size mismatch for
`int'
"